# Redshift - Insert data from pandas dataframe using Redshift Data API

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

I trying to load data that I have in a pandas data frame into a Redshift cluster using AWS lambda. I can't use a connector with the redshift endpoint url because the current VPC setup doesn't allow this connection.
What I can do is use the [Redshift Data API](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/big-data/using-the-amazon-redshift-data-api-to-interact-with-amazon-redshift-clusters/). Which works like this:

```
redshift_data_api_client = boto3.client('redshift-data')
redshift_database = 'my_redshift_db'
DbUser = 'my_user'
ClusterIdentifier = 'my_redshift_cluster'

query = '''
    select *
    from some_schema.some_table t 
    limit 10
    '''
res = redshift_data_api_client.execute_statement(
            Database=redshift_database, DbUser=DbUser, Sql=query,    
            ClusterIdentifier=ClusterIdentifier)
time.sleep(10)
query_id = res["Id"]
response = redshift_data_api_client.get_statement_result(
                Id=query_id)
```

The problem is that I haven't been able to integrate the Redshift Data API with a pandas dataframe. Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
redshift_data_api_client.insert_from_pandas(table, my_dataframe)
```

If that's not an option, I'd like to generate the INSERT SQL statement as string from the data frame, so I could do:

```
insert_query = my_dataframe.get_insert_sql_statement()
res = redshift_data_api_client.execute_statement(
            Database=redshift_database, 
            DbUser=DbUser, 
            Sql=insert_query,    
            ClusterIdentifier=ClusterIdentifier)
```

But I couldn't find a way to do that either. Pandas has a to_sql function, but it sends the data directly to a db connection (which I don't have), it doesn't generate the INSERT statement as string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: A better approach would be to write the dataframe to S3 and use the Data API to perform a COPY. Is there any reason that you can't do that?

Comment: Yes, that's an option I was thinking about. But I figured that if the data is already in lambda, there might be a way to load it into redshift without involving other services. However, given my current limitations, S3 is probably the best way to go

Comment: Those comments were meant for a different question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand this last comment

Comment: I accidentally wrote some comments here that were meant for another question. At one time SO would email comments, so if you saw them I wanted you to know that they weren't relevant.